# how i can send gzip instade deflate by skip header

Tags: c++, gzip, zlib, deflate

i write a c++ http server ( Microsoft http server api )

that send html page file in gzip format

and gzip file is static

for example file page1.htm and page1.htm.gz are in same directory

according to
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip

i know that gzip is deflate with extra header
and deflate is part of gzip

how i can sending gzip instade deflate by skip header

```
fileHandle=CreateFile( "page1.htm.gz"  ,dwAccess,dwShare,NULL,dwCreationFlags,dwAttributes,NULL);

....


ADD_KNOWN_HEADER(response, HttpHeaderContentEncoding, "deflate" );

HTTP_DATA_CHUNK dataChunk;
{     
   HTTP_DATA_CHUNK dataChunk;
   response.EntityChunkCount         = 1;                        
   dataChunk.DataChunkType           = HttpDataChunkFromFileHandle;
   dataChunk.FromFileHandle.FileHandle   =fileHandle;
   dataChunk.FromFileHandle.ByteRange.StartingOffset.QuadPart =9;// 9 is gzip header len
   dataChunk.FromFileHandle.ByteRange.Length.QuadPart = HTTP_BYTE_RANGE_TO_EOF;
   response.pEntityChunks=&dataChunk;
}     

 .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **deflate** and **gzip** encoding are not quite the same thing, although the differences are minor.

When you are sending gzip, change your code to:

```
ADD_KNOWN_HEADER(response, HttpHeaderContentEncoding, "gzip" );
```

You should do that of course if gzip is listed in `Accept-Encoding`.

Here's an excerpt from the gzip FAQ:

> “ What's the difference between the "gzip" and "deflate" HTTP 1.1
>   encodings?
>
> "gzip" is the gzip format, and "deflate" is the zlib format. They
>   should probably have called the second one "zlib" instead to avoid
>   confusion with the raw deflate compressed data format. While the HTTP
>   1.1 RFC 2616 correctly points to the zlib specification in RFC 1950 for the "deflate" transfer encoding, there have been reports of
>   servers and browsers that incorrectly produce or expect raw deflate
>   data per the deflate specficiation in RFC 1951, most notably
>   Microsoft. So even though the "deflate" transfer encoding using the
>   zlib format would be the more efficient approach (and in fact exactly
>   what the zlib format was designed for), using the "gzip" transfer
>   encoding is probably more reliable due to an unfortunate choice of
>   name on the part of the HTTP 1.1 authors.”
>
> http://www.gzip.org/zlib/zlib_faq.html#faq38